# How to add a class to li which could be the first, second or third parent of input with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to add a class called 'focused' to a parent li when I click a input field with jquery.

```
<form action="http://localhost/daikon2/index.php/projects/admin/newproject" method="post"><ul id="createproject">
<li id="proname" class="">
<label for='project_name'>Project Name</label>
<div><input type="text" name="project_name" value="" id="project_name" size="20"  /></div></li>

<li id="tothou" class="" >
<label for='total_hr'>Total hour</label>
<div><input type="text" name="total_hr" value="" id="total_hr" size="10"  /></div>
</li>
<li id="act" class=""><label for="active">Active</label><div><span>Yes<input type="radio" name="active" value="1" checked="checked" id="active" /></span><span>No<input type="radio" name="active" value="0"  /></span>

</div>
</li>
<li id="by" class""><label for='created_by'>By</label>
<div><select name="created_by">
<option value="admin">admin</option>
<option value="admin2">admin2</option>
</select></div>
</li><li id="noteli" class=""><label for='note'>Note</label>
<div><textarea name="note" cols="90" rows="12" id="note" ></textarea></div>
</li>
<li>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="6" />

</li>
<li id="submitbtn" class""><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create New Project"  /></li>
</form>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to crawl up to the nearest parent matching the selector, like this:

```
$(":input").focus(function() {
  $(this).closest("li").addClass("focused");
}).blur(function() {
  $(this).closest("li").removeClass("focused");
});
```

[You an test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hLs7G/).  A few side notes: your `</form>` should be *after* the `</ul>` and the `#submitbtn` element needs an `=` for the `class""`.

Comment: Thanks for note for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking but you could try doing:

```
$(this).closest('li').addClass('foobar');
```